# is it possible to add boolean prop on indexed interface?

Tags: typescript

i  have an interface like this:

```
interface FormState {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

as it is indexed, i need to add a loading indicator so i want to add a loading which is a boolean prop, when i do this:

```
interface FormState {
  [key: string]: string;
  loading: boolean
}
```

i get error

> Property 'loading' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string index
>   type 'string'.

how can i add loading prop for that interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the index signature must be compatible with any named properties. An option would be to add `boolean` to the index signature:

```
interface FormState {
  [key: string]: string | boolean;
  loading: boolean
}
```

Another option is to use an intersection. Intersections do not check that the index of an intersection member is compatible with all properties in the intersection:

```
type FormState = {
  [key: string]: string;
} & {
  loading: boolean
}
```

Although there are problems with this approach:

1. No object literal can satisfy this type without an assertion (you will get an error that `boolean` is not assignable to `string` because of the index signature)
2. Dynamic access with a key, might produce a type inconsistent with the runtime type if the dynamic key happens to be `'loading'`

Ex:

```
let f = {
    loading: true
} as FormState
let v = f['loading'] // boolean
let k = 'loading' as string;
let v2 = f[k] // string
```